# Probability that uniform random subsets $S_1\subseteq\dots\subseteq S_m$

Tags: probability

Pick (not necessarily distinct) subsets $S_1,\dots,S_m\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$ uniformly at random. What is the probability that $S_1\subseteq S_2\subseteq\dots\subseteq S_m$?

I have solved the problem for $m=2$. Conditional on $|S_2|=k$, the probability that $S_1\subseteq S_2$ is $\frac{2^k}{2^n}$. So by law of total probability,
$$\mathbb P(S_1\subseteq S_2)=2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n2^k\cdot\mathbb P(|S_2|=k)=2^{-2n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k=2^{-2n}(1+2)^n=\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^n.$$
But already for $m=3$ the sums are becoming unmanageable. Perhaps there is another perspective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for $1\leq i,j\leq m$ and $1\leq k,\ell\leq n$, the events $\{k\in S_i\}$ and $\{\ell\in S_j\}$ are independent (unless of course $k=\ell$ and $i=j$). Now say that some $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ is *good* if one of the following (mutually exclusive) conditions hold:

- $k\in S_1, k\in S_2,k\in S_3,\dots,k\in S_m$.
- $k\not\in S_1, k\in S_2,k\in S_3,\dots, k\in S_m$.
- $k\not\in S_1, k\not\in S_2,k\in S_3,\dots, k\in S_m$.

  $\vdots$
- $k\not\in S_1, k\not\in S_2,k\not\in S_3,\dots, k\not\in S_m$.

Then $S_1\subseteq\dots\subseteq S_m$ iff *every* $k$ is good. The probability a given $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ is good is $\frac{m+1}{2^m}$, so the probability that all $k$ are good is $\left(\frac{m+1}{2^m}\right)^n$.

Answer (score 1):

In a good configuration, for every $i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ there is $k \in \{0,\ldots,m\}$ such that $i \in S_l$ for $l>k$, but $ i\not\in S_l$ for $l \leq k$. (if needed, use $S_0 = \phi$ and $S_{m+1} = \{1,\ldots,n\}$).

Now, these are $m+1$ groups, so in total $(m+1)^n$ "good cases", the total ones are clearly $(2^n)^m = 2^{nm}$.

So, our probability is $$ \Big(\frac{m+1}{2^m} \Big)^n$$